# Psql | How can I select data with column name and sort its value as JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL 11 and I'm looking for a way to selecting and sorting the values from column "money, charm, luck, wit, health" and group them under **primaryAttr** (L & XL) or **secondaryAttr** (M) according to it's value.

Here is the example table: [product]

```
| **id** |   price  |  money  | charm  |  luck  |  wit  | health |
|--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+-------+--------|
| 158001 |   1500   |    M    |   XL   |    L   |   M   |   M    |
| 158002 |   2000   |    L    |   M    |    M   |   XL  |   L    |
```

and I'd like to get this following result: [product]

```
|     id    |   price   |               primary_attr                    |                   secondary_attr              |
|-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------|
|   158001  |   1500    |   {"luck": "L", "charm": "XL"}                |   {"wit": "M", "money": "M", "health": "M"}   |
|   158002  |   2000    |   {"wit": "XL", "money": "L", "health": "L"}  |   {"luck": "M", "charm": "M"}                 |
```

JSON result:

```
{ 
  "id":"158001",
  "price":"1500",
  "primaryAttr": {
    "charm": "XL",
    "luck": "L"
  },
  "secondaryAttr": {
    "money": "M",
    "wit": "M",
    "health": "M"
  }
},
{ 
  "id":"158002",
  "price":"2000",
  "primaryAttr": {
    "money": "L",
    "wit": "XL",
    "health": "L"
  },
  "secondaryAttr":{
    "charm": "M",
    "luck": "M"
  }
}
```

I've looked around for a solution but could not find anything like this yet. I'm trying to put things together and see if there is any good solution to this. I will put any updates here once I made any progress. Has anyone done anything similar that could point me into the right direction? Thanks for help and advice!

*setup data for testing* I forgot to add this in (thanks to @Oto Shavadze).

```sql
create table product(id int, price numeric, money text, charm text, luck text,  wit text, health text);
insert into product  
values 
(158001, 1500, 'M','XL','L','M','M'),
(158002, 2000, 'L','M','M','XL','L');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
-- just setup  data 
create table product(
id int, 
price numeric, 
money text, 
charm text, 
luck text,  
wit text, 
health text
);

insert into product
values  
(158001 ,  1500   , 'M','XL','L','M','M'),
(158002 ,  2000   ,  'L','M','M','XL','L');

-- actual query:
select v from 
product
join  lateral 
 jsonb_build_object('id', id, 'price', price, 
    'primaryAttr', 
    case 
    when money in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('money', money) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when charm in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('charm', charm) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when luck in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('luck', luck) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when wit in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('wit', wit) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when health in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('health', health) else '{}'::jsonb
    end,

    'secondaryAttr', 
    case 
    when money in('M') then jsonb_build_object('money', money) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when charm in('M') then jsonb_build_object('charm', charm) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when luck in('M') then jsonb_build_object('luck', luck) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when wit in('M') then jsonb_build_object('wit', wit) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when health in('M') then jsonb_build_object('health', health) else '{}'::jsonb
    end
     ) j(v)
  on true;
```

**EDIT**

```
select id, price, 
case 
    when money in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('money', money) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when charm in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('charm', charm) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when luck in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('luck', luck) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when wit in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('wit', wit) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when health in('XL','L') then jsonb_build_object('health', health) else '{}'::jsonb
end as primaryAttr,
case 
    when money in('M') then jsonb_build_object('money', money) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when charm in('M') then jsonb_build_object('charm', charm) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when luck in('M') then jsonb_build_object('luck', luck) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when wit in('M') then jsonb_build_object('wit', wit) else '{}'::jsonb
    end ||
    case 
    when health in('M') then jsonb_build_object('health', health) else '{}'::jsonb
end as secondaryAttr
from 
product;
```

DEMO: https://rextester.com/AXYUL76207

Comment: Apologies for the confusion @Oto Shavadze. I meant to get the attributes part as JSON. the JSON example I showed was the result I'd get from the application. I have edited my question and added in the desired result.

Comment: @GameBoy  - Edited answer, added new query, which you possibly need

Comment: Thanks! That's it. We were able to get something similar but yours works great. Do you think this would be slow if it was to run on a bigger scale data? If so, what methods would you recommend looking into that could improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You could unpivot and reaggregate:

```
select t.id, t.price, a.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select array_agg(attr) filter (where val in ('L', 'XL')) as primaryAttr,
             array_agg(attr) filter (where val in ('M')) as secondaryAttr             
      from (values ('money', t.money), ('charm', t.charm), ('wit', t.wit), ('luck', t.luck), ('health', t.health)
           ) v(attr, val)
     ) a;
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff! I tried running [this](https://rextester.com/LTUKA38880) and got 42601: syntax error at or near "as"
> https://rextester.com/LTUKA38880

Comment: @GameBoy . . . Missing closing parens.  Fixed.